# Vector images in R vignettes

Tags: r-package

I'm creating some vignettes using .Rmd files and knitr::rmarkdown.
When generating HTML output, my plots are being created as PNG images, then included in the vignette.  I'd rather that they were included as vector images.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found [an answer](https://yihui.name/knitr/options/) to this question: add `dev='svg'` ('dev' abbreviates 'device') to the `{R}` block:

```
{R Chunk name, echo=FALSE, [...], fig.height=3,  dev='svg'}
```